# jquery autocomplete return data

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

**Here is my 1st page. Below is the autocomplete:**

```
      <script>
          $(function() {
            $("#skills").autocomplete({
              source: 'search.php', 
                  minLength:1,
            select: function(event,ui){ *//autocomplete*
              var code = ui.item.id;
              if(code != '') {

              }
            }
            });
          });
          </script>
```

**My search.php page**

```
  $query = $db->query("SELECT *       
                         FROM patient  
                         WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$searchTerm%'  
                         OR MiddleName LIKE '%$searchTerm%'  
                         OR LastName LIKE '%$searchTerm%'  
                         OR PatientId LIKE '%$searchTerm%'");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['FirstName']." ".$row['MiddleName']." ".$row['LastName'];
        $id = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['PatientId'])); *//i want to pass this value*
    }
    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
```

I used jQuery autocomplete. I want to pass the `$id` value back to the 1st page. How can I pass it? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an array with label and value for each item

```
$label = $row['FirstName']." ".$row['MiddleName']." ".$row['LastName'];
$value = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['PatientId'])); 
$data[] = array('label' => $label, 'value' => $value);
```

Comment: it wont search if I add this :(

Comment: What do you mean? Have you tried? jQuery autocomplete supports this format also.